# Parse function declaration Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to define a cloud code method that send a push notification, however I am having a hard time declaring and calling the methods. I need a method to take 3 string parameters `tracking`, `slug` and `channel` I know how I would write these in Java or some other OOP language.

`private void sendNotification(String tracking, String slug, String channel)`

And to call `sendNotification("someTracking", "someSlug", "someChannel");`

How would I write these methods in the Parse JS SDK?

Comment: Is your question about how to define a function in JavaScript?

Comment: @iForests Based on the tag, I guess this is about the parse framework.

Comment: Parse js SDK is based on Backbone. maybe you can have a look at backbone first :)

Comment: A normal JavaScript function will do.

Comment: If you're looking to create a Cloud Code function, Parse has a complete documentation section about this. https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code

Answer (score 0):

You can declare Cloud Code functions like outlined in the guide Bjorn posted (https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code). To help you out in this case, below is the sample of a method definition that will behave like you desire.

```
/**
 * Send Push Notification
 * Required:
 * tracking                          -- Tracking String
 * slug                              -- Slug String
 * channel                           -- Channel String
 */
Parse.Cloud.define("sendNotification", function(request, response) {
               // Obviously you don't need to assign these variables, but this is how you access the parameters passed in
               var tracking = request.params.tracking;
               var slug = request.params.slug;
               var channel = request.params.channel;
               // Send your push notification here, I'm not gonna write the whole thing for you! :)
                   // In the callback of your push notification call:
                   response.success();
                   // For a successful send and response.error() if it fails or an error occurs
               });
```

To call this method in a client, assuming you're using java since you used java syntax in your question statement, you can follow this pattern as outlined in the Cloud Code Guide (referenced earlier):

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("tracking", "TRACKING_STRING");
params.put("slug", "SLUG_STRING");
params.put("channel", "CHANNEL_STRING");
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendNotification", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
   void done(ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // Your function was successful
       } else {
          // Your function failed, handle the error here
       }
   }
});
```

**However, if you're simply trying to send a push notification from the client, you should probably just use Parse's built in functions outlined here: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/Android**